# Reading yaml file with refrence in python

Tags: python, yaml

demo.yaml

```
content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            title: YamlTitle
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                "$ref": "definitions.yaml#/name"
            required:
              - data
```

**definitions.yaml** File data

```
  name:
    type: string
    minLength: 10
    example: GANESH
```

I want to read yaml file with its refrence data.

**Output**
result =  {'content': {'application/json': {'schema': {'title': 'YamlTitle', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'name': {'type': 'string', 'minLength': 10, 'example': 'GANESH'}}, 'required': ['name']}}}}

Comment: Check out [OpenAPI Python parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097285/swagger-openapi-python-parser). They can probably resolve $refs automatically.

Comment: It is not working as expacted.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is working as expected? What code have you tried and what result did you get?

Comment: Actually I want the result as an output result is displayed above with swagger API v3 . So in v3 [OpenAPI Python parsers].(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097285/swagger-openapi-python-parser)  does not work.

Comment: Thanks Helen prance library works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using a custom constructor & yaml loader where you add an YAML instruction that will do the trick.

Check https://davidchall.github.io/yaml-includes.html for example

Comment: It did not work, It prints same YAML data in JSON formate